# Stopping traffic to unhealthy web server instance from loadbalancer

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, mod-jk, mod-proxy-balancer

I have 3 web  servers (Apache) which are behind vip (Apache, serving as a reverse proxy). We dont want LB to serve traffic if the anyone of web server which has 501 error.

How can I do that automatically.

PS: I am thinking is to use health checks as part of mod_proxy (under balancemember attribute).

Answer (score 1):

I afraid you use wrong tool for LB. Apache can do that but it's not designed specially for that. My suggestion is to use HAProxy which is typical software for that situation.
If you need help with HAProxy just write. I could try to help but not ealier then on weekend.

ps. I created this account just to answer you :) I really know what I'm talking about. You want to use HAProxy instead of apache.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually in our production we have the configuration defined in terms of Apache only (from H/W load balancer to Apache is already handled.). Since our use case was restricted to Apache, thus we have implemented using mod_proxy only.